# Как дать ссылку на объект префабу

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть префаб, который создается с помощью кода.
И есть текст который на сцене изначально.
Как изменять текст со скрипта который на прифабе?
Есть, также объект, который создает этот прифаб

Comment: Можно искать по имени с помощью `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll` хотя я уверен что есть варианты получше

Comment: почему просто не передать ссылку скрипту, создающему префаб, что бы он передал ссылку префабу?

Comment: Я уже так сделал, все получилось